# Make a layout container for all blades

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-vue

I am creating a laravel-vuejs mix version of my vanilla vuejs app and in my vuejs app, I have a master component container for all my components. it goes like this...

**MainContainer.vue**

```
<template>
   <div>
       <topnav/>
       <sidenav/>
   
       <div class="content">
          <router-view/> //whichever component it is
       </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

I wanted this kind of structure in my laravel-vuejs mix app,

So far, I have this: 
`layout > master-container.blade.php` 
`modules > module1-blade.php` 
        `> module2-blade.php` 
        `> and so on...`

the **master-container.blade.php** looks like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body >
    <div id="vue-app" v-cloak>
        @yield('content')
    </div>
   <scripts here>
</body>
</html>
```

and my module blades looks like this...

```
@extends('layout.master-container')
@section('content')
   <module1 inline-template>
      @include('topnav')
      @include('sidebar')
      ..contents here
   </module1>
@ensection
```

Now when I check in `vue-devtools`

The components placement is not what I wanted it to be. it goes like this :

```
<Root>
    <Module1>
        <Topnav>
        <Sidenav>
```

Where it should look like this:

```
<Root>
    <Topnav>
        <Sidenav>
            <Module1>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have a div with id `vue-app`. Assuming this is your Vue instance, you can use your components as you would before, in any blade view that extends this layout.

Register your Vue components in your `app.js` file, as such:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app'
});
```

Then you can use your Vue components in the same manner as you did before. No need to put them in Blade includes.

Comment: I have an edit, I hope it would be a help

Comment: Are you adding Vue components as blade includes? i.e. is `@include('topnav')` a Vue component?

Comment: No need to do that, just use them as would a Vue component `<topnav>` as long as they are registered in your `app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your the content of your includes (not @include) in master blade file just before @yield content, and arrange them to obtain the desired output
For more precise response, you must post more detailed code (sidenav, topnav,...content)

Comment: No, this would mean that topnav and content will be rendered at the same time and content outside topnav, what I wanted is that topnav to be rendered first and then inside topnav, is the content component.